# Angular Mock ActivatedRoute using Snapshot and ParamMap

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking, karma-jasmine

I'm using this, from [here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#extract-the-id-route-parameter):

```
constructor(private heroService: HeroService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    const heroId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.heroService.getHeroById(heroId).subscribe((hero: Hero) => {
        ...
    });
}
```

Now I have a unit test that needs to mock this ActivatedRoute. I've already check some answers here in stackoverflow but without luck.

**Notice that I'm using snapshot.paramMap** so many solutions do not work at all. For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46823177/how-to-unit-test-a-angular-4-component-which-uses-router-parammap), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40789637/how-to-mock-an-activatedroute-parent-route-in-angular2-for-testing-purposes), and [this](https://gist.github.com/benjamincharity/3d25cd2c95b6ecffadb18c3d4dbbd80b) do not work.

I think the near valid answer could be:

```
{
    provide: ActivatedRoute,
    useValue: {paramMap: Observable.of(convertToParamMap({id: 1}))}
}
```

But does not work either.

The error showing is:

```
Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'ng:///HeroesModule/HeroDetailComponent_Host.ngfactory.js'.
    error properties: Object({ INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1, DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2, HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3, WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4, INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5, NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6, NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7, NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8, NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9, INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10, INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11, SYNTAX_ERR: 12, INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13, NAMESPACE_ERR: 14, INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15, VALIDATION_ERR: 16, TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: 17, SECURITY_ERR: 18, NETWORK_ERR: 19, ABORT_ERR: 20, URL_MISMATCH_ERR: 21, QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22, TIMEOUT_ERR: 23, INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24, DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25, code: 19 })
```

This is because I'm doing a request that responses with status 500 because **paramMap is undefined** so there is no id on the request.

... any ideas?

Thanks and BR

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add snapshot to the useValue like:

```
{
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {
            snapshot: {
              paramMap: convertToParamMap({
                id: '1'
              })
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: This didn't work until I changed the syntax a bit. This worked:
``` 
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {
            paramMap: of(
              convertToParamMap({
                'dynamic-id': '3',
                'another-dynamic-id': '2',
              })
            ),
          },
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

In recent Angular versions, a project's `aot` setting is on by default (for better compile-time type checking). If this is the case with your project, then you probably need to at least stub out all the properties of ActivatedRoute and ActivatedRouteSnapshot. Something like this:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Type } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { MockPlatformLocation } from '@angular/common/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { ActivatedRoute, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Params, ParamMap, convertToParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { of, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';
import { Hero } from '../hero';


export class MockActivatedRouteSnapshot implements ActivatedRouteSnapshot {
  private innerTestParams?: Params;

  constructor(params?: Params) {
    if (params) {
      this.testParams = params;
    } else {
      this.testParams = null;
    }
  }

  private get testParams() {
    return this.innerTestParams;
  }

  private set testParams(params: Params) {
    this.innerTestParams = params;
  }

  get paramMap() {
    return convertToParamMap(this.testParams);
  }

  get queryParamMap() {
    return this.paramMap;
  }

  get url() {
    return null;
  }

  get fragment() {
    return null;
  }

  get data() {
    return null;
  }

  get outlet() {
    return null;
  }

  get params() {
    return this.innerTestParams;
  }

  get queryParams() {
    return this.innerTestParams;
  }

  get component() {
    return null;
  }

  get routeConfig() {
    return null;
  }

  get root() {
    return null;
  }

  get parent() {
    return null;
  }

  get firstChild() {
    return null;
  }

  get children() {
    return null;
  }

  get pathFromRoot() {
    return null;
  }
}


export class MockActivatedRoute implements ActivatedRoute {
  private innerTestParams?: Params;
  private subject?: BehaviorSubject<Params> = new BehaviorSubject(this.testParams);
  private paramMapSubject?: BehaviorSubject<ParamMap> = new BehaviorSubject(convertToParamMap(this.testParams));

  constructor(params?: Params) {
    if (params) {
      this.testParams = params;
    } else {
      this.testParams = null;
    }
  }

  private get testParams() {
    return this.innerTestParams;
  }

  private set testParams(params: Params) {
    this.innerTestParams = params;
    this.subject.next(params);
    this.paramMapSubject.next(convertToParamMap(params));
  }

  get snapshot() {
    return new MockActivatedRouteSnapshot(this.testParams);
  }

  get params() {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }

  get queryParams() {
    return this.params;
  }

  get paramMap() {
    return this.paramMapSubject.asObservable();
  }

  get queryParamMap() {
    return this.paramMap;
  }

  get url() {
    return null;
  }

  get fragment() {
    return null;
  }

  get data() {
    return null;
  }

  get outlet() {
    return null;
  }

  get component() {
    return null;
  }

  get routeConfig() {
    return null;
  }

  get root() {
    return null;
  }

  get parent() {
    return null;
  }

  get firstChild() {
    return null;
  }

  get children() {
    return null;
  }

  get pathFromRoot() {
    return null;
  }
}


describe('HeroDetailComponent', () => {
  let component: HeroDetailComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeroDetailComponent>;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let routeMock: MockActivatedRoute;
  let initialMockParams: Params;
  let locationMock: MockPlatformLocation;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    initialMockParams = {id: 11};
    routeMock = new MockActivatedRoute(initialMockParams);
    locationMock = new MockPlatformLocation;
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [ HeroDetailComponent ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: routeMock,
        },
        {
          provide: Location, useValue: locationMock,
        }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeroDetailComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    httpMock = TestBed.inject<HttpTestingController>(HttpTestingController as Type<HttpTestingController>);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpMock.verify();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component).toBeTruthy();

    const dummyHero: Hero = { id: 11, name: 'dummyHero' };
    const req = httpMock.expectOne('api/details/11');
    req.flush(dummyHero);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer did not work for me until I changed the syntax a bit. This worked:

This didn't work until I changed a couple things. This worked:

```js
providers: [
 {
  provide: ActivatedRoute,
   useValue: {
    paramMap: of(
     convertToParamMap({
      'dynamic-id': '3',
      'another-dynamic-id': '2',
    })
   ),
  },
 },
],
```