# How to test method which is assigned to variable in function Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm working with Angular 13. I am trying to test a method assigned to variable that looks like this:

```js
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {}

compFunction(id: number) {
  if (id) {
    let result = this.returnFunction();
  }
}

returnFunction() {
  return this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
}
```

First I have tried this:

```js
it("should open foo page", inject((omitted)) => {
  component.compFunction('id')
  const data = component.returnFunction(); // not working this line
  data.toLowerCase();
}));
```

But I am getting the following error

> cannot read properties of undefined (reading: 'toLowerCase')

Secondly I tried to mock the function and assigned it but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have an `id` param in your route when doing the tests, so your `returnFunction` function returns undefined. You'll want to mock `route` to give it a `snapshot.paramMap` and provide it in your test bed.

[Angular Mock ActivatedRoute using Snapshot and ParamMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49917588/angular-mock-activatedroute-using-snapshot-and-parammap)